# ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, ruby-1.9.2

I am using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.4/3.0.5 and Phusion Passenger 3.0.3/3.0.4. My templates are written in HAML and I am using the MySQL2 gem. I have a controller action that when passed a parameter that has a special character, like an umlaut, gives me the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT)
```

The error points to the first line of my HAML template, which has the following code on it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My understanding is that this is caused because I have a UTF-8 string that is being concatenated with an ASCII-8BIT string, but I can't for the life of me figure out what that ASCII-8BIT string is. I have checked that the params in the action are encoded using UTF-8 and I have added an encoding: UTF-8 declaration to the top of the HAML template and the ruby files and I still get this error. My application.rb file has a `config.encoding = "UTF-8"` declaration in it as well and the following all result in UTF-8:

```
ENV['LANG']
__ENCODING__
Encoding.default_internal
Encoding.default_external
```

Here's the kicker: I cannot reproduce this result locally on my Mac-OSX using standalone passenger or mongrel in either development or production. I can only reproduce it on a production server running nginx+passenger on linux. I have verified in the production server's console that the latter mentioned commands all result in UTF-8 as well.

Have you experienced this same error and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After doing some debugging I found out the issue occurs when using the ActionDispatch::Request object which happens to have strings that are all coded in ASCII-8BIT, regardless of whether my app is coded in UTF-8 or not. I do not know why this only happens when using a production server on Linux, but I'm going to assume it's some quirk in Ruby or Rails since I was unable to reproduce this error locally. The error occurred specifically because of a line like this:

```
@current_path = request.env['PATH_INFO']
```

When this instance variable was printed in the HAML template it caused an error because the string was encoded in ASCII-8BIT instead of UTF-8. To solve this I did the following:

```
@current_path = request.env['PATH_INFO'].dup.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Which forced `@current_path` to use a duplicated string that was forced into the proper UTF-8 encoding. This error can also occur with other request related data like `request.headers`.

Comment: Having the Same error, i'm wondering why is this happening on production Nginx/passenger. It's having LC_All set properly. However request .env is ASCII. On a local Server its utf-8k

Answer (score 9):

Mysql could be the source of troublesome ascii. Try putting the following in initializer to at least eliminate this possibility:

```
require 'mysql'

class Mysql::Result
  def encode(value, encoding = "utf-8")
    String === value ? value.force_encoding(encoding) : value
  end

  def each_utf8(&block)
    each_orig do |row|
      yield row.map {|col| encode(col) }
    end
  end
  alias each_orig each
  alias each each_utf8

  def each_hash_utf8(&block)
    each_hash_orig do |row|
      row.each {|k, v| row[k] = encode(v) }
      yield(row)
    end
  end
  alias each_hash_orig each_hash
  alias each_hash each_hash_utf8
end
```

**edit**

This may not be applicable to mysql2 gem. Works for mysql however.

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but it's aimed at the mysql gem not the mysql2 gem. Mysql2 does not have this issue. Also, I get the same result regardless of whether or not I am querying the database.