# RSS Feed Entries - Encoding::CompatibilityError incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, rss, rss-reader

I am currently working on an RSS feed that was working for a while but now has an encoding issue. After trying many of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286117/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8) unsuccessfully, I have deduced that I may be having issues with the feed parser.

The error starts with the index page:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8):
11: 
12:           <div class="entry_wrapper">
13:             <div class="entry_box">
14:               <% feed.entries.each do |entry| %>
15:                 <p class="entry_title"><%= sanitize link_to entry.title, entry.url %></p>
16: 
17: 
  app/models/feed.rb:6:in `entries'
  app/views/feeds/index.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_feeds_index_html_erb__2672739530113604393_70126099705280'
  app/views/feeds/index.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_feeds_index_html_erb__2672739530113604393_70126099705280'
```

Here is larger section of the Feed#Index page:

```
<% @feeds.each do |feed| %>  # Line 5 here
      <p class="feed_url">
        <%= link_to feed.url, feed %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_feed_path(feed), class: "blue" %> 
        <%= link_to "Delete", feed_path(feed), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this feed url?' }, class: "blue" %>
      </p>

      <div class="entry_wrapper">
        <div class="entry_box">
          <% feed.entries.each do |entry| %>
            <p class="entry_title"><%= sanitize link_to entry.title, entry.url %></p>
```

I deleted the Feed URL's in the console so the page rendered fine without any urls to pull from. However, as soon as I added one, I got the same error as before.

I tried testing the encoding of the Feed entries in the console and got the following error:

```
2.1.1 :001 > g = Feed.last
  Feed Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "feeds".* FROM "feeds"   ORDER BY "feeds"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Feed id: 9, name: nil, created_at: "2016-01-18 05:01:54", updated_at:   "2016-01-18 05:01:54", url: "http://feeds.feedburner.com/MattsTravelSite"> 
2.1.1 :002 > g.entries
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/entities.rb:77:in `gsub'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/entities.rb:77:in `decode'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/entity_decoder.rb:14:in `decode'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/entity_decoder.rb:5:in `try_decode'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/sax_parser.rb:151:in `on_text'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/parser.rb:541:in `_rule_33'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/parser.rb:239:in `block in each_token'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/lexer.rb:237:in `call'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/lexer.rb:237:in `add_token'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/lexer.rb:439:in `on_element_end'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/lexer.rb:190:in `advance_native'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/lexer.rb:190:in `block in advance'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/lexer.rb:137:in `read_data'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/lexer.rb:189:in `advance'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/parser.rb:236:in `each_token'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/oga-2.0.0/lib/oga/xml/parser.rb:269:in `parse'
... 20 levels...
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I double-checked to see if the website I am pulling from is in UTF-8 encoding at the W3C-Validator website:

```
This document was successfully checked as well-formed XML!
Result: Passed, 1 warning(s)
Address:    
http://feeds.feedburner.com/MattsTravelSite
Encoding:   utf-8   
Doctype:    XML 
Root Element:   feed
Root Namespace: http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
```

I tried "forcing" the encoding in the model, but I think my coding skills are a little lacking in terms of creating methods. Here is the entries model I created originally for the Feed that is being used in the Feed#Index.

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def entries(num = 3)
    Feedjira::Feed.add_common_feed_entry_element("img")
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url)
    feed.entries.take(num)

    # add_items(feed.entries)  # Saving items to database
  end
....
```

Since this model was working before, I'm not sure what happened. I did take a few months from the app so I don't know if anything changed with Feedjirra. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216822/actionviewtemplateerror-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8 ?